# centos сервер перестает отвечать после service network restart

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование

Создаю виртуальный свитч br0, меняю настройки eth0. Далее после service network restart пишет

```
Failed to restart network.service: Unit is masked.
```

Делаю

```
systemctl unmask network
systemctl enable network
systemctl restart network
```

Далее сервер перестает отвечать, с чем может быть связано?